# Why does XHTML not work outside with a prefix?

Tags: xhtml, xml-namespaces, semantic-markup

To my eyes, this should be a valid XHTML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<a:html xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a:head>
        <a:title>Document title</a:title>
    </a:head>
    <a:body>
        <a:h1>Hello World!</a:h1>
    </a:body>
</a:html>
```

However, it is not handled like XHTML by neither Firefox nor Internet Explorer, instead showing as text (with tags not visible). If I remove the namespace prefix…

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Document title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

… it is rendered fine. I would have thought that both documents are semantically equal. Why does the first one not work?

Comment: http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/xhtml/ns.xhtml works fine in Chrome and Firefox when I test it.

Comment: To clarify, a file with an extension of `.html` is a HTML file, no matter if it has XHTML content or not. (That's the reason the second one works, because it contains mostly valid HTML content.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make sure that browsers get the hint to interpret the document as `application/xhtml+xml` (or possibly one of the other [XML MIME types](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/infrastructure.html#xml-mime-type)) instead of `text/html`.

**On a server**, you can achieve this by sending the corresponding `Content-Type` HTTP header:

```
Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml
```

**Locally**, you can typically achieve this by using `.xhtml` instead of `.html` as file extension (but this might depend on your system).

Comment: Note that the vast majority of servers also handle `.xhtml` files correctly, returning a mime type of application/xhtml+xml for those files by default.